# Update 'vw' command line call to reference most current vowpal_wabbit installation

Tags: bash, unix, vowpalwabbit

I recently updated my installation of vowpal wabbit by manually deleting the vowpal_wabbit directory and reinstalling according to the instructions at https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Tutorial.

I needed access to the `--link=logistic` option, which my older installation didn't have. Currently the command:

```
~/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/vw -d test_vw.vw -t -i lg.vw --link=logistic -p raw_predictions.txt
```

gives me what I want, whereas

```
vw -d test_vw.vw -t -i lg.vw --link=logistic -p raw_predictions.txt
```

hangs. It seems that only by explicitly declaring the path to the most current implementation of `vw` am I able to get the result I'm looking for.

This is probably more of a Unix/BASH question, but how do I update the short call to `vw`? I've had similar difficulties using vw-varinfo for what I suspect are similar reasons.

Comment: `alias vm=~/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/vw`. In your `~/.bashrc`. Or you might want to update your `PATH`: `export PATH=~/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit:$PATH` again in your `~/.bashrc`. If you need that in a noninteractive script, you should look into the `BASH_ENV` environment variable.

Comment: that should do it, thanks for the help!

Comment: Setting `PATH` correctly to include the directory where your `vw` resides is the correct way to fix this.  An `alias` would work only in the shell where it is defined, and not propagate to new process invocations.  e.g. `vw-varinfo` is such a process (calling `vw`)

Comment: thanks for this. for reasons i still don't totally understand my mac's home directory lacks both a `.profile` and a `.bashrc` file. using `sudo nano /etc/profile` i was able to manually insert path references that are called every time i open up a new terminal window.